# Rails Exception Notification without middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an Rails 4 application that is entirely comprised of rails runners over cron generated from the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

I'd like to be notified if there are any exceptions that occur during the run. The [exception_notification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) gem only runs as rack middleware (web requests only), so it doesn't handle rails runners.

Any ideas? I'm looking to get notified over email or on slack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception` in a rescue block to send a notification.

For example:

```
def rescue_exception(data)
  yield
rescue => e
  ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(e, data: data)
end

every :hour do
  rescue_exception(runner: 'SomeModel.some_method') do
    runner "SomeModel.some_method"
  end
end
```

Please refer to https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#background-notifications. Use `data` hash to pass additional information about the context.

Comment: is there anyway to do this so that you don't have to do it for every job?